# Calling methods with specific values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

For this code example below, usually I would use `[self fall];` instead of the code at *, but I need the value of `i` to be sent to the `fall` method as well. How do I do this?

```
- (void)main {
    for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
        [image[i] fall]; *
    }
}

- (void)fall {
    // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

EDIT: I will accept the oldest answer as all are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do -

```
 - (void)fall:(int)i {
     // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

and call like -

```
- (void)main {
for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
    [image fall:i];
}
```

}

EDIT -

If you want to pass index-

```
 - (void)fall:(int)i {
     // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

and call like -

```
- (void)main {
for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
    [self fall:i]; // Now from here you can either pass index
}
```

}

If you want to pass some image -

```
 - (void)fall:(UIImage)i {
     // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

and call like -

```
- (void)main {
for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
    [self fall:imageI]; // Now from here you need to pass image, if that image is stored in array, then fetch from array. Or you need to manipulate in the way in which you are storing.
}
```

}

Comment: Hey when I do it this way I get the warning "'UIImageView' may not respond to 'fall:'" and the app freezes when the loop runs. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it will. Because method is of view controller and if you call that with image object, it will definitely fail. Earlier i think image is some controller name. Check Edited post.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you mean:

```
- (void)main {
    for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
        [image[i] fall:i];
    }
}

- (void)fall:(int)i {
    // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

Or, maybe you mean:

```
- (void)main {
    for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
        [self fall:image[i]];
    }
}

- (void)fall:(NSImage *)image {
    // manipulate image[i]; separately from the for loop
}
```

If not, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Hey when I do it the top way I get the warning "'UIImageView' may not respond to 'fall:'" and the app freezes when the loop runs. Any ideas?